# Linq EF Split Parent into multiple Parents

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Using Entity Framework to query a database with a `Parent` table and `Child` table with a `1-n` relationship:

```
public class Parent {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF, here's a quick sample query:

```
var parents = context.Parents;
```

Which returns:

```
parent id = 1, children = { (id = 1), (id = 2), (id = 3) }
```

What we need is for this to flatten into a `1-1` relationship, but as a list of parents with a single child each:

```
parent id = 1, children = { (id = 1) }
parent id = 1, children = { (id = 2) }
parent id = 1, children = { (id = 3) }
```

We're using an OData service layer which hits EF.  So performance is an issue -- don't want it to perform a `ToList()` or iterate the entire result for example.

---

We've tried several different things, and the closest we can get is creating an anonymous type like such:

```
var results = from p in context.Parents
              from c in p.Children
              select new { Parent = p, Child = c }
```

But this isn't really what we're looking for.  *It creates an anonymous type of parent and child, not parent with child.  So we can't return an `IEnumerable<Parent>` any longer, but rather an `IEnumerable<anonymous>`.  The anonymous type isn't working with our OData service layer.*

Also tried with `SelectMany` and got 3 results, but all of `Children` which again isn't quite what we need:

```
context.Parents.SelectMany(p => p.Children)
```

Is what we're trying to do possible?  *With the sample data provided, we'd want 3 rows returned -- representing a List each with a single Child.  When normally it returns 1 Parent with 3 Children, we want the Parent returned 3 times with a single child each.*

Comment: **But this isn't really what we're looking for**, so what are you looking for? The LINQ query that you mentioned gives you flattened results like the ones you described. If you're having some issues with it, describe them so we can help you.

Comment: @RacilHilan -- We've updated the question with italics.  Let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is not a supported feature, as any sane developer would consider it a bug. What you likely actually want is to construct a `ParentDto` class which you should be mapping to.

Comment: I'm with Aron, smells like there is something amiss on the other end, but then I wont judge. Select from the child end and then actually form the parent, 'select new Parent{}' and assign each child and parent appropriately.

Comment: So using Linq (with EF), there is no way of converting a Parent with 3 Children into 3 Parents with 1 child each?  Imagine the sql representing the results -- they come back in 3 rows, but EF combines those into 1 row with 3 children.  Basically we want 3 rows, with 1 child each...  Wondering if it's just limitations with our OData service layer.

Comment: what you're trying to do does not make much sense. All references to an  entity is the same. So you want 3 Parents but with different `Children`, that's possible only when 3 parents are ***diferent references***. To have different references to the same entity, you can use `AsNoTracking` but you cannot do all in just 1 line-query, e.g: to have 3 parents, you need 3 queries - which is less efficient. Another way is using `new` operator but then you need to prepare some local list before projecting using `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements don't make any sense, the idea behind how EF and LINQ work is not those repetitive info like SQL does. But you know them better and we don't know the whole picture, so I will try to answer your question hoping I understood it correctly.

If like you said, your problem is that `IEnumerable<anonymous>` doesn't work with your OData service layer, then create a class for the relationship:

```
public class ParentChild {
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use in in your LINQ query:

```
var results = from p in context.Parents
              from c in p.Children
              select new ParentChild { Parent = p, Child = c }
```

Comment: This is close to what we implemented, but OData doesn't support complex types, so we've had to list each property individually.  Not ideal, but appears to be working.  Thanks for your help.  In regards to requirements, I agree -- challenging to understand without tons of more background information.